# Comparing string date to actual date in Excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel

I have a date in cell A1 in text format - May 18

Using VBA, is it possible, to positively compare this value to the value in cell A2 - 01/05/2018 (UK date format)?

I've tried using the CDate function, but it does not return the correct value. For example, If the value in A1 was Nov 24, CDate reurns 24/11/2018.

So, what I want to do is :-
If A1 = May 18
AND A2 = 01/05/2018
THEN TRUE

Comment: `May 18` - which day? And what is wrong with `CDate()`?

Comment: See my edit re CDate

Comment: So the idea is to compare the same month? Ignoring the day?

Comment: If you enter `?range("A1").Formula` into the immediate window of the VBE, what is the result?

Comment: "I've tried using the CDate function, but it does not return the correct value. For example, If the value in A1 was Nov 24, CDate reurns 24/11/2018." - this is the expected result, what are you expecting/trying to get it to return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `DATEVALUE`:

```
=DATEVALUE("1 " & $A$1)=$A$2
```

Will return TRUE if 1st of the month in cell A1 is the same as the date in cell A2.

Comment: @pnuts It will return False.  `=DATEVALUE("1 " & $A$1)` resolves to _43221_, 1st May 2017 is _42856_.

Comment: @pnuts I read it as 18th May first off which makes it harder to answer as then didn't know the year.  The third paragraph of the question says _Nov 24_ returns 24/11/2018 which is not what the OP wants.  It can't be 11th of the 24th month so the only other date it could be is _November 2024_.  Simples :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Excel formula:

```
=TEXT("18 May","dd-mm-yyyy")
```

Or in VBA:

```
Dim Dt As Date
Dt = CDate(Range("A1"))
Dim Compare As Boolean
Compare = Dt = Range("A2")
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, which explains how to compare a date stored as text in A1 and a date stored as a date in A2

Answer (score 0):

With VBA, consider:

```
Sub DateCompaison()
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String, d2 As Date
    s1 = [A1].Text
    s2 = [A2].Text

    arry1 = Split(s1, " ")
    arry2 = Split(s2, "/")

    month1 = arry1(0)
    year1 = "20" & arry1(1)

    d2 = DateSerial(CInt(arry2(2)), CInt(arry2(1)), CInt(arry2(0)))
    month2 = Format(d2, "mmmm")
    year2 = CStr(Year(d2))

    If month1 = month2 And year1 = year2 Then
        MsgBox "the same"
    Else
        MsgBox "not the same"
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]